# Access windows shared folders from linux with php

Tags: php, security

I need to be able to access some shared folders on a number of windows server using a php script running on a Linux server. I only need to get the names of the files contained in the folders and the timestamp for when they where created.

The only solution I've come up with so far is to mount the share in Linux and access it from there. While this solves the problem, I have to do it as root (as far as I'm aware) which means that I either have to run scripts as root which is just plain stupid, or manually mount all shares which will be a serious pain to manage in the long run.

This leads to two questions.

1. Anybody know of a better way to do it? I have administrative rights on all machines if that should be needed.
2. What are the security issues I have to deal with here? I need to overcome the root problem, and I need to guarantee that the linux/php script can't edit/delete files on the windows machine, but I guess that there might be more problems than those lurking in the dark.

Comment: Why aren't you using `/etc/fstab` to mount the filesystems at boot?

Comment: I could but I would still be stuck with mounting everything manually, which will be a problem when I suddenly have 100 or so different windows servers I need to handle. Ideally I would like my php script to read the name of the windowsservers from our server inventory database, check that the required files are in the correct folder on that server (by mounting and then unmounting the folder if needed, or by directly accessing the folder on the server if possible) and then continue with the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having several hundred servers come and go with great enough frequency that editing `/etc/fstab` to add new filesystems is definitely an annoying constraint.

If all you're doing is listing files and modification times on the server, then the `smbclient(1)` command is a good starting point. `smbclient(1)` is a lot like an FTP interface for SMB and CIFS shares. The `-c` command line option lets you run a specific command; something like:

```sh
smbclient //$servername/$sharename -c "dir path/to/directory/"
```

If you're going to be doing more with the file than just listing modification times, then mounting the share as a filesystem will reduce the number of connect and authentication requests, and perhaps make parsing `stat(2)` output far easier than parsing plain-text representations of the data.

If you want to go down the route of mounting your filesystems, first split apart your script.

One small piece should take a servername, share path, and an optional mount path; it adds the (server, share, path) to `/etc/fstab`.

This portion could be setuid root. (Which is dangerous, but beats running the entire PHP script as root.)

Or, you could mount your filesystems with `acl(5)` support and add a new access control entry:

```
mount / -oremount,acl
setfacl -m www::rw /etc/fstab
```

Now the `www` user has privileges to modify the `/etc/fstab` file. (Note that I haven't actually tested `addmntent(3)` when ACLs have been used to give a user write access to `/etc/fstab`.) Be sure to modify `/etc/fstab` to always mount `/` with `acl` support, so this works across reboots.

You can use the `addmntent(3)` C library function to add new entries to `/etc/fstab`. I'd pick C over a scripting language if you're going to use a setuid root executable, and I'd probably pick C over a scripting language anyway, because `addmntent(3)` already knows how to write correctly formatted mount entries to `/etc/fstab`.

Include the `user` and `noauto` options so your script can run unprivileged and still mount shares as it needs them.

Comment: A colleague of mine also had some theories about using smbclient, and your other ideas was very helpful. Thanks.