# Trying to access a windows shared folder through php (laravel) on a linux machine using scandir

Tags: php, laravel, scandir, network-share

Good afternoon everyone, I'm trying to access a windows shared folder on the same network through php (laravel) using the scandir method. here is some sample code

```
$dir = '\\\\192.168.1.18\\Data';
$files = scandir($dir);
return $files;
```

I've tried different ways to type the server address (\192.168.1.18\Data and so forth).

I get a `scandir(\\192.168.1.18\Data): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can check if it's a problem with the shared folder or with the PHP by replacing scandir with this simple linux command:

```
exec("ls \\\\192.168.1.18\\Data",$result);
print_r($result);
```

if you will get an error **No such file or directory** so you have problem with the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815390/access-windows-shared-folders-from-linux-with-php) might help you. It suggests mounting the Windows share in Linux.